# Want the EditText to display in all Activitys

Tags: android, android-edittext

First of, I'm a noob in Android development....

So, my problem is - I have a Activity with a EditText view, so someone can put his name in it.
And what I want to do with that input - I want it to be displayed in all activities in TextViews where it needs to be.
Example - Like in a book -> Input name: What are you doing kid? Kir: "I don't know..." Input name: "Just don't do it anymore..."ect.

And then in the next Activity by clicking a Button, the same, I want that same input name to display in ALL ACTIVITES , TextViews where it needs to be, but I don't know how to declare it, where to declare it, what code ect.

I hope you all will understand what i mean.

And thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by passing data into intents before starting the activity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key_name", "John Cena");
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Then retrieve the data in MyActivity by:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = extras.getString("key_name"); // name should be John Cena
```

Simillar functionality also exists for Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you wants to **Preserve** the **Value\Data**. For such scenarios, it is best to use `[Preferences]` where you can save your data on disk in a private file and read it anytime and anywhere.

[Android Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)